# How can I put a link inside of a text string in HAML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

This should probably be easier than it is. I just want to put a link inside an HTML paragraph element.

```
%p{class: "answer"}="Please upload your data to this portal in text (tab-separated) format. Download our template #{raw(link_to 'here', '/templates/upload_template.xlsx')} for sample data and a description of each column."
```

Rails is encoding the tag information. I don't want tags to be encoded. I want them to be tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [interpolation directly in Haml](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#ruby_interpolation_), and doing this seems to fix the issue in this case.

So instead of doing this:

```
%p= "Text with #{something_interpolated} in it."
```

you can just do

```
%p Text with #{something_interpolated} in it.
```

i.e. you don’t need the `=` or the quotes, since you are just adding a single string. You shouldn’t need to use `raw` either.

(Also, note you can do `%p.answer` to set the `class` attribute, which may be cleaner if the value isn’t being set dynamically.)

---

*Why* this is being escaped here is a different matter. I would have expected the two cases (`%p= "#{foo}"` and `%p #{foo}`) to behave the same way. However, after a bit of research,  this behaviour seems to match how Rails behaves with Erb.

Answer (score 3):

You can use more than one line inside any block, to solve your problem we will have something like this:

```
%p{class: "answer"}
  Please upload your data to this portal in text (tab-separated) format. Download our template 
  = link_to 'here', '/templates/upload_template.xlsx'
  for sample data and a description of each column."
```

Comment: and while we are at it we could encourage the `p.answer` syntax. Much nicer than `%p{class: "answer"}`